# Switch to pop up window using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to switch to a popup window but I am having trouble doing so. The link that I click on is to redirect me to an email popup window.

My code is:

```
public String determineIfCorrectUrlOnPopUp() {

    clickOnEmailThisSeller();
    for (String currentWindow: driver.getWindowHandles()) {

        driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
    }

    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    return driver.getCurrentUrl();

}
```

but it prints out the parent window URL instead of the popup window. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String determineIfCorrectUrlOnPopUp() {

clickOnEmailThisSeller();

// Below Line in your code will switch to  the current window  by using for each loop
for (String currentWindow: driver.getWindowHandles())
       driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
{
   //Now you are in Popup window and you can get the pop-up window URL here
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.close();  
}

System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // This will return Parent window URL
return driver.getCurrentUrl();

}
```

Comment: This one worked, thank you very much! I am not sure why mine didn't work.

Comment: Rupesh, can you explain your syntax? Why is there braces after `    driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);`?

Comment: I would say  inside that braces we will have to include the code to work on Pop-up window or in simple way you consider it be a template which we will always use to handle such situation. I have explain the Template here .Please check    http://rupeshrshinde.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-switch-to-different-browser.html

Comment: I really don't understand your syntax. Is the syntax you're using java?

Comment: Robben yes its in Java

Comment: I am having issues. It works sometimes and it doesn't work other times. 
I did for (String currentWindow: driver.getWindowHandles())
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
        {
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }

but it prints out the parent's window instead.

Comment: Yes beacuse youre missing    "for ( String currentwindow : driver.getWindowHandles())"   and it should be written before    driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
driver.switchTo().window(handle).getCurrentUrl();
```

I haven't done a lot of this but I did write a little function that closes popup windows and I used

```
driver.switchTo().window(handle).close();
```

to close the popup.