# How we can use swapping method using selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

The command for web driver

driver.switchTo().window("windowName");

please  comment for selenium ide..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch to pop up window using Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012582/switch-to-pop-up-window-using-selenium)

Comment: This is the Selenium method to switch between windows. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012582/switch-to-pop-up-window-using-selenium). Also, make sure to browse through Stack Overflow before you ask. A lot of similar questions have been answered in the past.